# ajax responseText 'undefined'

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i'm using ajax in my codeigniter project but whenever i send data i get error and the response will be 'Undefined'.
i built the simplest code i've ever imagine but nothing works.
would you please tell me where is the wrong ??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        var content = "test";
        var datastring = 'content='+ content;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo site_url('test/test'); ?>",
            data: datastring, 
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) { alert("succsess"); },
            error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText); },
            onComplete: function(data) {alert(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my codeigniter code is :

```
function test() {
    echo $this->input->post('content');
}
```

Comment: Try `complete` instead of `onComplete`

Comment: i just add complete to cover all cases but error case is activated whenever i run my code

Comment: what is the status code? maybe, the route is not defined?

Comment: No, you're error is likely caused by passing an invalid setting key (onComplete).

Comment: status is "error" @vijayst

Comment: maybe, @EatPeanutButter is right. Fixing onComplete might make it work.

Comment: perfect .. thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

ErrorText is the last parameter of error callback.

```
error: function(xhr, status, errorText) {
  alert(errorText);
}
```

Comment: New reponse ((NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'))

Answer (score 0):

You should use `complete` in the place of `oncomplete`. The re-written code will be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        var content = "test";
        var datastring = 'content='+ content;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo site_url('test/test'); ?>",
            data: datastring, 
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) { alert("succsess"); },
            error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText); },
            complete: function(data) {alert(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
```